# How to specify a different non-pypi package index url to setuptools.setup?

Tags: python, artifactory, setuptools

I'm trying to specify a package dependency not in pypi [but in jfrog/Artifactory] to `setuptoools.setup()`

Things I've tried:

1. Using the `dependency_links` argument to `setuptools.setup()` like so:

   dependency_links=['http://USER:PASSWORD@ARTIFACTORYHOST:8082/api/pypi/pypi/simple']

but  [dependency_links is now deprecated since 19.0 (released 2019-01-22).](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/16137c686c619c0133e7bc2aef9b85d1a34b68fe/docs/deprecated/dependency_links.rst#L5-L6)

2. Using the `install_requires` argument to `setuptools.setup()` like so:

   install_requires=[mypackage @ http://USER:PASSWORD@ARTIFACTORY HOST:8082/api/pypi/pypi/simple]

but `install_requires` seems to expect to download source code as a [.zip] archive.

Ideally, I'm looking for something equivalent to pip's `extra-index-url` setting, which is specifiable directly to `setuptools.setup()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From abravalheri
at
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3364:

> I couldn't find anything in the latest packaging standards about
> mixing multiple package indexes together directly on the package
> specification. You need to use an external tool for that, like the pip
> configuration file, or a package index mirror/proxy like devpi (maybe
> bandersnatch also can do that?).
>
> What is possible to do right now is to force a URL to a wheel file as
> covered in [PEP 440](https://peps.python.org/pep-0440/#direct-references)/PEP 508. But as you have already noticed, it
> requires you to point to a specific file and don't allow for dynamic
> version resolution.
>
> So the short answer is no, unfortunately there seems to be nothing in
> the packaging standards regarding that.